# Error: protect (): protection stack overflow when running text analysis

Tags: r

I am trying to run a linear discriminant analysis on a large corpus of text in RStudio (on a MacBook Pro), R version 3.4.1. Based on other questions I have set the max ppsize.

```
options(expressions = 5e5)
```

Below is a reproducible example that throws the same error. Any advice?

```
library(tm)
library(MASS)

shakespeare.v<-scan("https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.182303/2015.182303.Shakespeare-Complete-Works_djvu.txt",what="character",sep="\n",)


docs<-Corpus(VectorSource(shakespeare.v))

toSpace <- content_transformer(function(x, pattern) {return 
(gsub(pattern, " ", x))})

docs<-tm_map(docs,content_transformer(tolower))

docs<-tm_map(docs, removePunctuation)
docs<-tm_map(docs, removeNumbers)
docs<-tm_map(docs, toSpace, "page")
docs<-tm_map(docs, stripWhitespace)
docs<-tm_map(docs, toSpace, "filename")

full.words.l<-gsub("[^[:alnum:][:space:]']", " ", docs)
full.words.l<-strsplit(full.words.l, "\\s+")

full.words.v<-unlist(full.words.l)

full.l.3000 <- split(full.words.v, 
ceiling(seq_along(full.words.v)/3000))


chunks.v.3000<-unlist(full.l.3000)


chunks.c.3000<-Corpus(VectorSource(full.l.3000))

matrix.3000<-matrix(chunks.c.3000)

dtm.3000<-DocumentTermMatrix(chunks.c.3000)
m.3000<-as.matrix(dtm.3000)
df.3000<-as.data.frame(m.3000)

lda.3000<-lda(full.l.3000~.,
      df.3000, na.action = "na.omit", CV=TRUE)
```

Comment: This works fine on a subset of the full data set you are using? At what size does it fail? Have you checked the RAM usage as it runs? etc.

Comment: I'm a newbie to all this, so I'm not sure the value of working on a subset? I'll try to check RAM; I think it fails at 15608, though I'm not really sure how to interpret some of the outputs. Thanks tho, I'll try some more.